# AJAX data handling via PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, wordpress

I have sent data using AJAX. I have used this code. I can handle & recive `productInfo:JSON` data using PHP but can't be handling `datastring`. Because showing like below image. How can handle or receive `datastring` using PHP? 
[image]

```
var datastring = jQuery("#chackOutBillingIfor").serialize();
jQuery.ajax({
      url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=chackOut",  
      data: {
              productInfo:JSON.stringify(cart), 
              billingInfo:JSON.stringify(datastring),
            },
      type: 'POST',
      cache: false,
})
```

Comment: `billingInfo` is a JSON-serialized form-encoded string. You want to either skip the `.serialize()` part or the `JSON.stringify` part for it. Or you need to decode it again both ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the `billingInfo` string on the `&` to get a list of key and value strings and then split those strings on `=`. The following function should be sufficient to return an array from the value.

```
function stringToArray($str)
{
    $result = array();
    foreach (explode('&', $str) as $pair) {
        list ($key, $val) = explode('=', $pair);
        $result[$key] = $val;
    }
    return empty($result) ? false : $result;
}
```

You may want to perform a check that the string contains at least one `=` and it cannot be in first position before processing the string.